# Inchoo’s FB Connect Magento module doesn’t work on custom theme

Tags: magento

Inchoo’s FB Connect module doesn't work on custom theme, but does on the default theme. So obviously the custom theme is missing something or having a conflict with it, which I need to figure out.

Are there any general things which I need to look for?

I found out that it attaches its output to `after_body_start` block, but on custom theme it doesn’t output its FB related markup and script over there. Mage’s Google analytics code is output in the html at the same block and that is working fine, so I am a bit lost here.

Inchoo's fb connect module xml - https://github.com/ivanweiler/Inchoo_Facebook/blob/master/app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/inchoo/facebook.xml

Also `page.xml` of the custom theme has this reference:

`<block type="core/text_list" name="after_body_start" as="after_body_start" />`

Complete `page.xml` of custom theme:

```
<default translate="label" module="page">
    <label>All Pages</label>
    <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/2columns-left.phtml">

        <block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">

            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js</name></action>       
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>slides-carousel/slides.min.jquery.js</name></action>         
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>slides-carousel/slides-init.js</name></action>

            <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs" ifconfig="dev/js/deprecation"><script>prototype/deprecation.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>lib/ccard.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/validation.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/builder.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/effects.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/dragdrop.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/controls.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/slider.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/js.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/form.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/menu.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>mage/translate.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>mage/cookies.js</script></action>            

            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/styles.css</stylesheet></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/styles-ie.css</name><params/><if>lt IE 8</if></action>
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/niceforms-default.css</stylesheet></action> 
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/widgets.css</stylesheet></action>
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/print.css</stylesheet><params>media="print"</params></action>
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>slides-carousel/slides.css</stylesheet></action>
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/niceforms-default.css</stylesheet></action>             

            <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>lib/ds-sleight.js</name><params/><if>lt IE 7</if></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/niceforms.js</name></action>                  
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/ie6.js</name><params/><if>lt IE 7</if></action>

        </block>

        <block type="core/text_list" name="after_body_start" as="after_body_start"/>

        <block type="page/html_notices" name="global_notices" as="global_notices" template="page/html/notices.phtml" />

        <block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header">
            <block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks"/>
            <block type="page/switch" name="store_language" as="store_language" template="page/switch/flags.phtml"/>
            <block type="core/text_list" name="top.menu" as="topMenu"/>
            <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="top.container" as="topContainer" translate="label">
                <label>Page Header</label>
                <action method="setElementClass"><value>top-container</value></action>
            </block>
            <block type="directory/currency" name="currency" template="directory/currency_small.phtml"/>
            <block type="page/switch" name="ie" as="ie" template="page/ie/ie6.phtml"/>
        </block>

        <block type="page/html_breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs" as="breadcrumbs"/>

        <block type="core/text_list" name="left" as="left" translate="label">
            <label>Left Column</label>
        </block>

        <block type="core/messages" name="global_messages" as="global_messages"/>
        <block type="core/messages" name="messages" as="messages"/>

        <block type="core/text_list" name="content" as="content" translate="label">
            <label>Main Content Area</label>
        </block>

        <block type="core/text_list" name="right" as="right" translate="label">
            <label>Right Column</label>
        </block>

        <block type="page/html_footer" name="footer" as="footer" template="page/html/footer.phtml">
            <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="bottom.container" as="bottomContainer" translate="label">
                <label>Page Footer</label>
                <action method="setElementClass"><value>bottom-container</value></action>
            </block>
            <block type="page/switch" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" template="page/switch/stores.phtml"/>
            <block type="page/template_links" name="footer_links" as="footer_links" template="page/template/links.phtml"/>
        </block>

        <block type="core/text_list" name="before_body_end" as="before_body_end"/>
    </block>

    <block type="core/profiler" output="toHtml" name="core_profiler"/>
</default>

<print translate="label" module="page">
    <label>All Pages (Print Version)</label>
    <!-- Mage_Page -->
    <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/print.phtml">

        <block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
            <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>mage/translate.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>lib/ccard.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/validation.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/js.js</script></action>

            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/styles.css</stylesheet></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/styles-ie.css</name><params/><if>lt IE 8</if></action>
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/widgets.css</stylesheet></action>
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/print.css</stylesheet><params>media="print"</params></action>

            <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>lib/ds-sleight.js</name><params/><if>lt IE 7</if></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/ie6.js</name><params/><if>lt IE 7</if></action>

        </block>

        <block type="core/text_list" name="content" as="content" translate="label">
            <label>Main Content Area</label>
        </block>

    </block>
</print>

 <!-- Custom page layout handles -->
<page_empty translate="label">
    <label>All Empty Layout Pages</label>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/empty.phtml</template></action>
        <!-- Mark root page block that template is applied -->
        <action method="setIsHandle"><applied>1</applied></action>
    </reference>
</page_empty>

<page_one_column translate="label">
    <label>All One-Column Layout Pages</label>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        <!-- Mark root page block that template is applied -->
        <action method="setIsHandle"><applied>1</applied></action>
    </reference>
</page_one_column>

<page_two_columns_left translate="label">
    <label>All Two-Column Layout Pages (Left Column)</label>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
        <!-- Mark root page block that template is applied -->
        <action method="setIsHandle"><applied>1</applied></action>
    </reference>
</page_two_columns_left>

<page_two_columns_right translate="label">
    <label>All Two-Column Layout Pages (Right Column)</label>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
        <!-- Mark root page block that template is applied -->
        <action method="setIsHandle"><applied>1</applied></action>
    </reference>
</page_two_columns_right>

<page_three_columns translate="label">
    <label>All Three-Column Layout Pages</label>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/3columns.phtml</template></action>
        <!-- Mark root page block that template is applied -->
        <action method="setIsHandle"><applied>1</applied></action>
    </reference>
</page_three_columns>
```

Where else should I be looking for?

Comment: Again a downvote without any explanation. I think the world is gonna end in 2012.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding ,you want to [use inchoo's facebook-connect-magento-extension](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/facebook-connect-magento-extension/) in your custom theme.
However I managed to use fb connect in my custom theme.
 I did the following changes.
**Step 1:** After downloading the inchoo's facebook-connect-magento-extension,on opening the app folder ,copied `Inchoo` folder from `/app/code/community/` and paste into `/app/code/local/` in your installed magento_folder.
**Step 2:** Copy 'layout' and 'template' from `/app/design/frontend/default/default` and paste it under your theme folder `theme_folder/`.
**Step 3:** Copy 'Inchoo_Facebook.xml' from `app/etc/modules` into your `app/etc/modules` and **edit** `Inchoo_Facebook.xml` change `<codePool>community</codePool>` to `<codePool>local</codePool>` like this

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Inchoo_Facebook>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Inchoo_Facebook>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**Step 4:** Copy `/app/locale` to `/app/locale` in your magento folder
**P.S** : Apply permission.
Hope this helps.

Comment: So basically you are saying that moving the extension to local codePool will make it work? What difference does it make? Unfortunately I don't have that project to try this anymore.

Comment: Fine,the difference it makes is everything is in custom part and the main part (our goal) it works in custom theme.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on that? I am unable to follow your point.